# How can I set a constant number as the lowest number in a column?

Tags: mysql, update

Here is my query?

```
UPDATE users 
SET reputation = reputation - (CASE WHEN id = 29 THEN 2 
                                    WHEN id = 30 AND NOT 0 THEN 15
                                    ELSE 0 
                               END)
WHERE id IN (30, 29);
```

Sometimes it throws this error:

> #1690 - BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(spy.users.reputation - (case when (spy.users.id = 29) then 2 when ((spy.users.id = 30) and (not(0))) then 15 else 0 end))'

As you see in the error message, `reputation` column is *UNSIGNED*, and I need to keep it `1` at least .. something exactly like stackoverflow: if a user has 1 rep and he gets a downvote, his rep will still remain `1`. Well how can I fix that update query to prevent failing in such a case?

---

Noted that using `greatest():` doesn't make any different. I mean [this won't work either](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfp6o.png):

```
UPDATE users 
    SET reputation = GREATEST(reputation -
                               (CASE WHEN id = 29 THEN 2 WHEN id = 30 AND NOT 0 THEN 15
                                     ELSE 0 END), 0)
WHERE id IN (30, 29);
```

Comment: `NOT 0` is always "true"; why is that part of the expression?

Comment: @RickJames Please take a look at [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WfCER.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET reputation = 
    GREATEST(1,
        CAST(reputation AS SIGNED) - ( ... )
            )
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @dezso - The `CAST` treats `reputation` as a signed INT, thereby avoiding the error message.  The `GREATEST` says "take 1 or that other expression, whichever is larger".  This prevents actually trying to store a negative number in the `UNSIGNED reputation`.  The `1` comes form the OP's requirements.  (Other answers read that as `0`.)

Answer (score 0):

[Based on Rick Jame's answer, but expands to include original question and explains the meaning]

Take the `GREATEST` clause and wrap it within a `CAST` to return it back to an unsigned type before it is used to update the field.

The `1` represents the greatest is the lowest value that can be stored in the reputation field, and is the number you can modify if you want to set a `minimum value`.

```
UPDATE users 
SET reputation = CAST(
    GREATEST(1,
        (reputation - (
            CASE
                WHEN id = 29 THEN 2
                WHEN id = 30 AND TRUE/FALSE THEN 15
                ELSE 0
            END
            ))
        )
    AS UNSIGNED)
WHERE id IN (30, 29)
```

The `TRUE/FALSE` piece is where the PHP script can inject the correct true or false value instead of the mySQL engine evaluating a boolean expression each time it executs.